# Outlook setup security certificate alert

Tags: windows, outlook

Our small company is moving our email server to an online Exchange server with the office365 business subscription. Currently, we have been using a linux server for our email server accessed via Outlook for all employees.

I have had no trouble setting up with the linux server. However, when we try to connect Outlook to the new office365 account, we get this error that prevents the setup:
[Popup error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e55Mh.png)

I must note that we do NOT have any issue setting Outlook up on a computer that is NOT joined to our company domain. We ONLY receive this error when trying to configure Outlook on a domain joined computer.

I've tried clicking "view certificate" to install the certificate but this does not seem to do anything.

I also deleted the certificate key in the local registry as per an online forum I searched but again to no avail.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The name from the ssl certificate do not match the real hostname which is used here. With the infos you provided I would say this is a selfsigned ssl certificate.

Comment: How would I be able to get the relevant certificate, and how exactly would I use it in this context?

Comment: That depends a little bit on your Exchange Online Setup. To help you we need to find out where the SSL certificate comes from. So if you ping the DNS name from the ssl certificate which server is behind that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean "from the ssl certificate" but I do have this information on the certificate information:

Issued to: [BOLIVIA]  (our windows domain name)
Issued by: {alliedsolution-BOLIVIA-CA]

It seems we are using a certificate assigned via our windows domain, if that helps.

Comment: The rule here is not to post any "company" information. So I wouldn´t be that specified. But yes. The "issued to" is the hostname and we need to find out to which IP this one responsed. It might be that you re-used an old DNS name with exchange online or something like that. Then the ssl certificate pushed out by your AD didn´t fit the exchange online server name.

Comment: Also check if the certificate is valid or expired
Adjust date time of system if required
check domain names